# Only ready lifecycle callback fires in Polymer 2

Tags: polymer, web-component, lifecycle, polymer-2.x

When I create a Polymer 2.0 element, only the `ready` lifecycle callback seems to fire, and I can't work out why. For example, I have this Polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="flip-four-board">
    <script>
        class FlipFourBoard extends Polymer.Element {            

            static get is() { return "flip-four-board"; }

            created() {
                super.created();
                console.log("created");
            }

            ready() {
                super.ready();
                console.log("ready");
            }

            attached() {
                super.attached();
                console.log("attached");
            }

            detached() {
                super.detached();
                console.log("detached");
            }

        }

        customElements.define(FlipFourBoard.is, FlipFourBoard);
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

But when I insert it into a page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flip Four Board Tests</title>
    <script src="../../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../flip-four-board.html">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            width: 95%;
            height: 95%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <flip-four-board></flip-four-board>
</body>
</html>
```

The console only reads:

### [image: console log]

Why is only the `ready` callback firing?

Comment: It looks like you need to read the [Polymer 2.0 upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Polymer 2.0 introduces several [lifecycle callback changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#lifecycle-changes), including the replacement of all but one of the original callbacks (i.e., `ready`) in the class-based element definitions. The legacy callbacks are still available when using the `Polymer` factory method in 2.0.

```
      1.x (legacy)    |      2.x
----------------------|-----------------------------
    created           |   constructor
    attached          |   connectedCallback
    detached          |   disconnectedCallback
    attributeChanged  |   attributeChangedCallback
    ready             |   ready
```

So, your class should look similar to this:

```
class FlipFourBoard extends Polymer.Element {

  static get is() { return "flip-four-board"; }

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("created");
  }

  ready() {
    super.ready();
    console.log("ready");
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    console.log("attached");
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    console.log("detached");
  }

}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zwWmqP?editors=1010)